# Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the shaded region about x-axis

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

**Question:- Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the shaded region about $x$-axis( The curve is $x=2y-y^3$)**.

[image]

I think we will not get overlapping volumes due to symmetry of the shaded regions about $x$-axis.

By Shell's method

$$V=2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}2\pi(y)(2y-y^3)\mathrm{dy}$$

Can somebody please verify?

Comment: Think of your solid as made up of discs centred on the $y$-axis. Their radius is $x$, what is their area? The volume of a thin disc should be $dy$ times its area, and you need to add up (integrate) this $dy$ times area.

Comment: @Joshua Tilley Is shell method expression correct here?

Comment: No the integral in your question does not give the volume. Your integrand is $2\pi yx$. Ask yourself, should $2\pi yx$ be the area of the discs?

Comment: What is the area of a disc of radius $r$?

Comment: @Joshua Tilley $\pi(2y-y^3)^2$

Comment: Yes, so if we integrate this area the volume should pop out.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley that's incorrect. OP is using shell method and the bounds and integral setup are both correct.

Comment: To OP, given the equation of the curve and that we are rotating about x-axis, shell method is the right approach and your setup is correct.

Comment: Math lover is right, I thought this was revolving around the $y$-axis, my mistake.

Comment: @Math Lover Thank you very much